# Drawing on OnPaint() makes residues when the window is resized

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a custom panel that draws a border (that comprises two rectangles). The problem is that if I resize the window, there remain residues... much like the animation of Windows XP's Solitaire. See the screenshot below. I resized the window to the right.

What is wrong, and how can I fix this?

[image: Resized window to the right]

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var outer = ClientRectangle;
    outer.Width -= 1;
    outer.Height -= 1;
    var inner = outer;
    inner.X++;
    inner.Y++;
    inner.Width -= 2;
    inner.Height -= 2;

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(DarkPen, outer);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(WhitePen, inner);

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

**UPDATE**

At first I thought this was because I did not delete the previously drawn rectangles. So I called `FillRectangle` to delete the inside.

```
var contentArea = inner;
contentArea.X++;
contentArea.Y++;
contentArea.Width -= 2;
contentArea.Height -= 2;
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, contentArea);
```

But it did not work either. It seems that the control paints only the newly expanded portion, not the entire area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Form class was optimized to be a container control.  Containers normally just have a background color to paint.  So, as you noticed, indeed does "only paint newly expanded portion".  Or more accurately, it does not overpaint the previous pixels, easy to recognize from the smearing effect that produces.  It is a somewhat feeble attempt at making Winforms designs a bit more lively when you resize the window, painting gets to be a bottleneck when a form has a lot of controls and that is pretty noticeable.

You'll have to set its ResizeRedraw property to true so it redraws its entire surface when necessary.  Setting the DoubleBuffered property to true might not hurt either when the drawing code gets elaborate and you start noticing flicker.

So, roughly:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
```

Optimizing OnPaint() is generally not a strategy that pays off, Windows itself already clips what you draw against the dirty region.

Comment: It works, but I just wonder if this is the recommended way. I mean, I know not all area needs to be redrawn (in the update above, I filled the entire content area just to be sure, as a quick and dirty solution). Can I specify the area that needs to be updated instead?

Comment: You don't specify the area, the operating system specifies it.  Passed to you as the e.ClipRectangle property.  Actually using it, meh, pretty hard to compete with the OS already using it.  Okay when you can avoid touching a lot of data in your own code when a drawing object falls completely outside of the clip rectangle.  What you have does not qualify for that by a long stretch.