# Why is groupbox a button in Win32 API? (BS_GROUPBOX)

Tags: c, windows, winapi

In Win32 API we create a groupbox with BS_GROUPBOX, where BS stands for button style and there are BS_PUSHBUTTON, BS_RADIOBUTTON, BS_CHECKBOX, BS_3STATE etc.

Pushbutton, radiobutton, checkbox and 3-state checkbox are really `buttons`, but how can a groupbox becomes a button? There seems not anything in common. For me I would rather call it a `static`.

Comment: This is honestly something Raymond Chen of The Old New Thing blog could maybe answer, SO less likely so. The Windows API has been designed in the early 90s (or late 80s), and it's still backward compatible, so warts like this are inevitable.

Comment: @AKX Thank you, I'll email him. This is an interesting topic.

Comment: Even Larry Osterman is not old enough to know the answer.  Fitting a GUI operating system and its apps in 256KB of memory required a lot of crazy tricks, code re-use is one basic one.  Somewhat plausibly, the BUTTON class is special because its CS_H/VREDRAW style flags are turned on.  Necessary to [paint correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190035/drawing-on-onpaint-makes-residues-when-the-window-is-resized) when the control gets resized.  A group box has that requirement as well, STATIC doesn't.

Comment: @HansPassant That should be the answer, thank you. The redraw theory may be the one.

Comment: @HansPassant Hello! Will you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? I forgot it one year ago. :D